# FirebaseListAdapter cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I tried to make a chat for android using a video tutorial but got an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TkD6.png

dependencies: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUwmI.png

```
    private void displayAllMessages() {
    ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
    adapter= new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(this, Message.class, R.layout.list_item, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
            TextView mess_user, mess_time, mess_text;
            mess_user = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            mess_time = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            mess_text = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);

            mess_user.setText(model.getUserName());
            mess_text.setText(model.getTextMessage());
            mess_time.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Please help me figure it out

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: I think this `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` is **not** returning the desired `Firebase` object which the constructor wants.

Comment: Please don't add code as images, add as a text.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a new version of FirebaseUI, then you need to change your code to the following:

```
FirebaseListOptions<Message> options =
            new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Message>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(), Message.class)
                     .setLayout(R.layout.list_item)
                    .build();
 adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(options){
 @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
        //...
       }
```

You can check here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview

for more informaiton